# Picking items from the magento database

Tags: magento-1.9, database, collection

I am trying to get the client email from the `sales_flat_order` table but I am not getting this way

```
public function getOrderbyemail()
{
    $email = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
               ->addFieldToFilter('customer_email', $email);

    foreach ($email as $customer_email) {
        $customer_email = $email->getCustomerEmail();
        print_r($customer_email->getCustomerEmail());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php 

    $customer_email = array('customer@gmail.com', 'customer2@gmail.com');
    $orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
                     ->addAttributeToFilter('customer_email', array('in' => $customer_email)) ; 

    foreach($orders as $order) {
        var_dump($order->getCustomerFirstname().'<br/>');
        var_dump($order->getCustomerLastname().'<br/>');
        var_dump($order->getCustomerEmail().'<br/>');
    }
?>
```

Comment: It is not giving error, but it is not printing the item on the screen in phtml `<?php echo $this->getOrderbyemail();  ?> ` in xml `<block type="contato/pedido" name="pedido" template="contato/contato.phtml"/>`

Comment: i didn't understand you put it in a function ?

Comment: I changed the role name
I'm calling it like this:



`Public function __construct () {`

Comment: Even calling directly in phtml is not working

Comment: it's not possible i tested it, copy again exactly all my code and put it in your phtml, replace the email adresses

Comment: Oh yeah, it worked, but in case I would have to put the emails that I would like to show? Is there any way I can get the data automatically without having to send email by email?

Comment: I diden't undesrtand, you want to get customer data not by email adress ? if it's the case you can replace them with `customer_id`for exemple

Comment: Yes I would like it, it's kind of complex to explain what I want, but you helped me a lot, I'll try to do here with attempts, what you helped me to do was what I needed most, I need to get the data by email Yes, but it would be the same Zip code system, the person puts the zip code and it pulls the street, I would like as soon as the customer put the email pull the order number, I already changed to the data I would like to get
`var_dump($order->getBaseGrandTotal().'<br/>');
        var_dump($order->getIncrementId().'<br/>');
        var_dump($order->getCreatedAt().'<br/>');`

Comment: If you can't do it, I suggest you to open a new post

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to go about getting a collection of orders by `customer_email`:

```
// email address that you are looking for
$search_email = 'example@email.com';

// this will get us a collection of all orders with our $search_email
$orderCollection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToSelect('*')
    ->addFieldToFilter('customer_email', $search_email);

// parse through our order collection
foreach ($orderCollection as $order) {
    // here, we are just getting and printing the email from the order
    // but you can get any column you like from sales_flat_order
    $customer_email = $order->getCustomerEmail();
    print_r($customer_email);
}
```

Comment: It looks like the first answer is allowing you to search by an array of email addresses.  I tried to explain each step with my comments.

Comment: `$order_collection` will contain all orders where the `customer_email` equals `$search_email`.  If `$search_email` was used on multiple orders, you will need to parse through the collection using `foreach`.